# the .c file formed by compiling a Makefile within genesis 2.3 produces error

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, makefile

error produced =

```
newconn_d@.c: In function ‘INFO_fac_synchan_type’:
newconn_d@.c:540: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
make[1]: *** [newconn_d@.o] Error 1
```

The source code:

```
/*including line 540 at start for your convenience because SUCH long code:
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.122";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.122))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="#";info.type_size=sizeof("");InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"122");strcat(fields,"\n");
*/



#include "newconn_ext.h"

#define __BZ BZERO(&info,sizeof(Info))
#define __IFI(F) info.field_indirection = F
#define __IFT info.function_type = 1
#define __IND(N) info.dimensions = N
#define __IDS(S,N) info.dimension_size[S] = N



....

__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.compositeobject";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.compositeobject))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="GenesisObject";info.type_size=sizeof(GenesisObject);__IFI(1);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"compositeobject");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field compositeobject\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.componentof";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.componentof))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="Element";info.type_size=sizeof(Element);__IFI(1);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"componentof");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field componentof\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.parent";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.parent))-(caddr_t)(&var);      info.type="Element";info.type_size=sizeof(Element);__IFI(1);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"parent");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field parent\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.child";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.child))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="Element";info.type_size=sizeof(Element);__IFI(1);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"child");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field child\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.next";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.next))-(caddr_t)(&var);      info.type="Element";info.type_size=sizeof(Element);__IFI(1);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"next");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field next\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.activation";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.activation))-(caddr_t)(&var);      info.type="float";info.type_size=sizeof(float);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"activation");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field activation\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.Ik";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.Ik))-(caddr_t)(&var);      info.type="double";info.type_size=sizeof(double);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"Ik");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field Ik\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.Gk";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.Gk))-(caddr_t)(&var);      info.type="double";info.type_size=sizeof(double);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"Gk");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field Gk\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.Ek";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.Ek))-(caddr_t)(&var);      info.type="float";info.type_size=sizeof(float);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"Ek");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field Ek\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.X";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.X))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="double";info.type_size=sizeof(double);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"X");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field X\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.Y";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.Y))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="double";info.type_size=sizeof(double);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"Y");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field Y\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.tau1";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.tau1))-(caddr_t)(&var);      info.type="float";info.type_size=sizeof(float);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"tau1");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field tau1\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.tau2";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.tau2))-(caddr_t)(&var);      info.type="float";info.type_size=sizeof(float);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"tau2");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field tau2\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.gmax";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.gmax))-(caddr_t)(&var);      info.type="float";info.type_size=sizeof(float);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"gmax");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field gmax\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.xconst1";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.xconst1))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="double";info.type_size=sizeof(double);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"xconst1");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field xconst1\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.xconst2";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.xconst2))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="double";info.type_size=sizeof(double);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"xconst2");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field xconst2\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.yconst1";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.yconst1))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="double";info.type_size=sizeof(double);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"yconst1");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field yconst1\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.yconst2";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.yconst2))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="double";info.type_size=sizeof(double);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"yconst2");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field yconst2\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.norm";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.norm))-(caddr_t)(&var);      info.type="float";info.type_size=sizeof(float);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"norm");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field norm\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.frequency";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.frequency))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="float";info.type_size=sizeof(float);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"frequency");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field frequency\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.nsynapses";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.nsynapses))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="short";info.type_size=sizeof(short);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"nsynapses");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field nsynapses\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.normalize_weights";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.normalize_weights))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="short";info.type_size=sizeof(short);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"normalize_weights");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field normalize_weights\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.time_last_event";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.time_last_event))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="double";info.type_size=sizeof(double);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"time_last_event");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field time_last_event\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.hsolve";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.hsolve))-(caddr_t)(&var);      info.type="Element";info.type_size=sizeof(Element);__IFI(1);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"hsolve");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field hsolve\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.solve_index";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.solve_index))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="int";info.type_size=sizeof(int);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"solve_index");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field solve_index\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.synapse_size";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.synapse_size))-(caddr_t)(&var);      info.type="unsigned short";info.type_size=sizeof(unsigned short);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"synapse_size");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field synapse_size\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.event_buffer_size";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.event_buffer_size))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="int";info.type_size=sizeof(int);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"event_buffer_size");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field event_buffer_size\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.pending_events";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.pending_events))-(caddr_t)(&var);      info.type="int";info.type_size=sizeof(int);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"pending_events");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field pending_events\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.FreeSynapticEvents";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.FreeSynapticEvents))-(caddr_t)(&var);      info.type="SynapticEventPtr";info.type_size=sizeof(SynapticEventPtr);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"FreeSynapticEvents");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field FreeSynapticEvents\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.PendingSynapticEvents";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.PendingSynapticEvents))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="SynapticEventPtr";info.type_size=sizeof(SynapticEventPtr);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"PendingSynapticEvents");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field PendingSynapticEvents\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.nodes_per_synapse";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.nodes_per_synapse))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="float";info.type_size=sizeof(float);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"nodes_per_synapse");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field nodes_per_synapse\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.list_alloced";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.list_alloced))-(caddr_t)(&var);      info.type="short";info.type_size=sizeof(short);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"list_alloced");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field list_alloced\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.allocednodes";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.allocednodes))-(caddr_t)(&var);      info.type="short";info.type_size=sizeof(short);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"allocednodes");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field allocednodes\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.synapse";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.synapse))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="Fac_Synapse_type";info.type_size=sizeof(struct Fac_Synapse_type);__IFI(1);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"synapse");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field synapse\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.122";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.122))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="#";info.type_size=sizeof("");InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"122");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field 122\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.max_fac";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.max_fac))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="float";info.type_size=sizeof(float);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"max_fac");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field max_fac\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.fac_per_spike";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.fac_per_spike))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="float";info.type_size=sizeof(float);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"fac_per_spike");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field fac_per_spike\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.fac_tau";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.fac_tau))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="float";info.type_size=sizeof(float);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"fac_tau");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field fac_tau\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.fac_const";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.fac_const))-(caddr_t)(&var);        info.type="float";info.type_size=sizeof(float);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"fac_const");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field fac_const\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.depr_per_spike";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.depr_per_spike))-(caddr_t)(&var);      info.type="float";info.type_size=sizeof(float);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"depr_per_spike");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field depr_per_spike\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.depr_tau";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.depr_tau))-(caddr_t)(&var);      info.type="float";info.type_size=sizeof(float);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"depr_tau");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field depr_tau\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.depr_const";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.depr_const))-(caddr_t)(&var);      info.type="float";info.type_size=sizeof(float);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"depr_const");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object fac_synchan_type, field depr_const\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
FieldHashPut("fac_synchan_type",fields);
}


void INFO_SynG_type(){
struct SynG_type var;Info info;char fields[2500];fields[0]='\0';info.name="SynG_type";info.type_size=sizeof(var);InfoHashPut(&info);
__BZ;info.name="SynG_type.name";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.name))-(caddr_t)(&var);     info.type="char";info.type_size=sizeof(char);__IFI(1);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"name");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object SynG_type, field name\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="SynG_type.index";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.index))-(caddr_t)(&var);       info.type="int";info.type_size=sizeof(int);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"index");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object SynG_type, field index\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="SynG_type.object";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.object))-(caddr_t)(&var);     info.type="object_type";info.type_size=sizeof(struct object_type);__IFI(1);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"object");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object SynG_type, field object\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="SynG_type.flags";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.flags))-(caddr_t)(&var);       info.type="short";info.type_size=sizeof(short);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"flags");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object SynG_type, field flags\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="SynG_type.nextfields";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.nextfields))-(caddr_t)(&var);     info.type="short";info.type_size=sizeof(short);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"nextfields");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object SynG_type, field nextfields\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="SynG_type.extfields";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.extfields))-(caddr_t)(&var);       info.type="char";info.type_size=sizeof(char);__IFI(2);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"extfields");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object SynG_type, field extfields\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="SynG_type.x";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.x))-(caddr_t)(&var);       info.type="float";info.type_size=sizeof(float);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"x");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object SynG_type, field x\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="SynG_type.y";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.y))-(caddr_t)(&var);       info.type="float";info.type_size=sizeof(float);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"y");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object SynG_type, field y\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
__BZ;info.name="SynG_type.z";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.z))-(caddr_t)(&var);       info.type="float";info.type_size=sizeof(float);InfoHashPut(&info);strcat(fields,"z");strcat(fields,"\n");
if (strlen(fields) > 2500) { Error(); printf("Field size too long for object SynG_type, field z\n**See sys/code_sym.c and increase the value of MAX_FIELDS_SIZE\n\n"); }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a macro named one of:

```
depr_const
depr_per_spike
depr_tau
fac_const
fac_depr_on
fac_per_spike
fac_tau
max_fac
```

which is defined as `122`. To track the name clash you can try to process the source file using cpp: `cpp -dD source.c`. Ans see which macro corrupts the compilation.

Comment: I think you're probably on the right track here.  Studying the structure definition for `fac_synchan_type` should identify the structure element that appears between `synapse` and `max_fac`; that is likely the macro that evaluates to 122.

Answer (score 0):

The complaint seems to be about:

```
__BZ;info.name="fac_synchan_type.122";info.offset=(caddr_t)(&(var.122))-(caddr_t)(&var);
```

You can't have a structure member called `122`, hence the syntax error at `var.122`.

Review how you've defined this structure.